# Calculate stock returns in pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to calculate the annual performance (as change in market value) of these two firms whose data is stored in the dataframe below.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'tic'      : ['AAPL', 'AAPL', 'AAPL', 'GOOGL','GOOGL','GOOGL'],
                   'mktvalue' : [20,25,30,50,55,60],
                   'fyear'    : [2014,2015,2016,2014,2015,2016]})
```

I have have seen a similar with solution a lambda function, but until now I couldn't adapt it to my data. I had a solution like this in mind to calculate the performance based on the year:

```
df['performance'] = df.fyear.apply(lambda x: (df.mktvalue[(df['fyear'] == 2014)]) / 
                    (df.mktvalue[(df['fyear'] == 2013)]) if x == 2014 
                    else (df.mktvalue[(df['fyear'] == 2013)]) /                
                    (df.mktvalue[(df['fyear'] == 2013)])
```

One of my major problems was that in the implementation when calling

```
(df.mktvalue[(df['fyear'] == 2013)])
```

I received all of the market values of 2013 instead of only the corresponding one to this firm.

I would appreciate any help!

Comment: Regardless of your problem, in the `else` branch, `(df.mktvalue[(df['fyear'] == 2013)]) / (df.mktvalue[(df['fyear'] == 2013)])` will always return 1. Is that what you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

is that what you want?

```
In [129]: df['performance'] = df.groupby('tic').mktvalue.pct_change().fillna(0)

In [130]: df
Out[130]:
   fyear  mktvalue    tic  performance
0   2014        20   AAPL     0.000000
1   2015        25   AAPL     0.250000
2   2016        30   AAPL     0.200000
3   2014        50  GOOGL     0.000000
4   2015        55  GOOGL     0.100000
5   2016        60  GOOGL     0.090909
```

Comment: not exactly, as I would want the percentage change only for AAPL over the three years and also the percentage change only for GOOGL for the three years. So for AAPL I would need 0 (20/20-1), 0.25 (25/20-1), 0.2 (30/25-1) and for GOOGL 0 (50/50-1), 0.1 (55/50-1), 0.09 (60/55-1)

Comment: this is exactly what I was looking for, thank you so much!